# How did my company firewall get URL from a HTTPS site?

Tags: tls

I tried to access Meetup at office. I then got a warning about bad HTTPS from Firefox 48, which I tried to set an exception for; I do see website owners make genuine mistakes of using old certificates, so I was not suspicious. I was surprised that the firewall got the URL which HTTPS was supposed to protect.

> The web site you are trying to access:
>   www.meetup.com/group/events/233/ is listed as a
>   site within the category SocialNetworking
>
> Current Internet Access Configuration for you does not allow visiting
>   sites within this category at this time.

How did the firewall break HTTPS?

Comment: @mzhaase my machine is a stock Ubuntu and I cannot access this site. Did I miss something?

Comment: You had a warning because your firewall did a MitM. You add an exception to continue. So now you speak securely to your company firewall (which speaks to Meetup). If you did read the warning you should see that information.